# Laravel (6.0) Route not found error - but route exists in route:list

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

I am trying to access a route from a package but I get route not found - even though the route shows when I am using the command php artisan route:list. I have tried clearing all cache but still no success? Everything works fine in my local environment so I am leaning towards a cache issue.

Error message is below:

> [previous exception] [object] (Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException(code: 0): Route [admin.affiliate_urls.index] not defined. at /home/forge/site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/UrlGenerator.php:437)
> [stacktrace]
> #0 /home/forge/site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php(777): Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator->route()
> #1 /home/forge/site/storage/framework/views/aed68191b7fd34274389d9db4a4a419e12790000.php(145): route()
> #2 /home/forge/site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Engines/PhpEngine.php(43): include('/home/forge/www...')
> #3 /home/forge/site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Engines/CompilerEngine.php(59): Illuminate\View\Engines\PhpEngine->evaluatePath()
> #4 /home/forge/site/vendor/facade/ignition/src/Views/Engines/CompilerEngine.php(36): Illuminate\View\Engines\CompilerEngine->get()
> #5 /home/forge/site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php(143): Facade\Ignition\Views\Engines\CompilerEngine->get()
> #6 /home/forge/site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php(126): Illuminate\View\View->getContents()
> #7 /home/forge/site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php(91): Illuminate\View\View->renderContents()
> #8 /home/forge/site/storage/framework/views/a6b35713f60cfc6d83afb428a6584b18d94c1e22.php(10): Illuminate\View\View->render()
> #9 /home/forge/site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Engines/PhpEngine.php(43): include('/home/forge/www...')
> #10 /home/forge/site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Engines/CompilerEngine.php(59): Illuminate\View\Engines\PhpEngine->evaluatePath()
> #11 /home/forge/site/vendor/facade/ignition/src/Views/Engines/CompilerEngine.php(36): Illuminate\View\Engines\CompilerEngine->get()
> #12 /home/forge/site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php(143): Facade\Ignition\Views\Engines\CompilerEngine->get()
> #13 /home/forge/site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php(126): Illuminate\View\View->getContents()
> #14 /home/forge/site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php(91): Illuminate\View\View->renderContents()
> #15 /home/forge/site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Response.php(42): Illuminate\View\View->render()
> #16 /home/forge/site/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Response.php(205): Illuminate\Http\Response->setContent()
> #17 /home/forge/site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(749): Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response->__construct()
> #18 /home/forge/site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(721): Illuminate\Routing\Router::toResponse()
> #19 /home/forge/site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(681): Illuminate\Routing\Router->prepareResponse()
> #20 /home/forge/site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(130): Illuminate\Routing\Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}()
> #21 /home/forge/site/vendor/Company/admingui/src/Middleware/AuthAdminUser.php(39): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()
> #22 /home/forge/site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(171): Company\Admingui\Middleware\AuthAdminUser->handle()
> #23 /home/forge/site/vendor/Company/core/src/Middleware/CampaignSession.php(37): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()
> #24 /home/forge/site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(171): Company\Core\Middleware\CampaignSession->handle()
> #25 /home/forge/site/vendor/Company/core/src/Middleware/UriRedirect.php(29): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()
> #26 /home/forge/site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(171): Company\Core\Middleware\UriRedirect->handle()
> #27 /home/forge/site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/SubstituteBindings.php(41): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()
> #28 /home/forge/site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(171): Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings->handle()
> #29 /home/forge/site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php(78): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()
> #30 /home/forge/site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(171): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken->handle()
> #31 /home/forge/site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Middleware/ShareErrorsFromSession.php(49): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()
> #32 /home/forge/site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(171): Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession->handle()
> #33 /home/forge/site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php(56): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()
> #34 /home/forge/site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(171): Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession->handle()
> #35 /home/forge/site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php(37): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()
> #36 /home/forge/site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(171): Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle()
> #37 /home/forge/site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/EncryptCookies.php(67): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()
> #38 /home/forge/site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(171): Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies->handle()
> #39 /home/forge/site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(105): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()
> #40 /home/forge/site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(683): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then()
> #41 /home/forge/site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(658): Illuminate\Routing\Router->runRouteWithinStack()
> #42 /home/forge/site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(624): Illuminate\Routing\Router->runRoute()
> #43 /home/forge/site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(613): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatchToRoute()
> #44 /home/forge/site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(170): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch()
> #45 /home/forge/site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(130): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}()
> #46 /home/forge/site/vendor/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar/src/Middleware/InjectDebugbar.php(60): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()
> #47 /home/forge/site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(171): Barryvdh\Debugbar\Middleware\InjectDebugbar->handle()
> #48 /home/forge/site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()
> #49 /home/forge/site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(171): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest->handle()
> #50 /home/forge/site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()
> #51 /home/forge/site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(171): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest->handle()
> #52 /home/forge/site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ValidatePostSize.php(27): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()
> #53 /home/forge/site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(171): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize->handle()
> #54 /home/forge/site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/CheckForMaintenanceMode.php(63): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()
> #55 /home/forge/site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(171): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle()
> #56 /home/forge/site/vendor/fideloper/proxy/src/TrustProxies.php(57): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()
> #57 /home/forge/site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(171): Fideloper\Proxy\TrustProxies->handle()
> #58 /home/forge/site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(105): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()
> #59 /home/forge/site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(145): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then()
> #60 /home/forge/site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(110): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter()
> #61 /home/forge/site/public/index.php(55): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle()
> #62 {main}
> "}

Output of php artisan route:list

> [...]
> |        | GET|HEAD                               | admin/affiliate-urls                                     | admin.affiliate_urls.index                               | Company\Admingui\Controllers\AdminAffiliateUrlController@index                                  | web,admin                                            |
> [...]

Content of web.php (routes in package)

> [...]
> Route::get('/admin/affiliate-urls','Company\Admingui\Controllers\AdminAffiliateUrlController@index')->name("admin.affiliate_urls.index");
> [...]

Comment: I am assuming you have already tried `php artisan route:cache` ?

Comment: I have, also php artisan cache:clear and config:clear

Comment: Everything works fine on your local, so the issue is on your server? If so, try running `php artisan optimize` once.

Comment: I have one route that uses a closure, so I am unable to use the command php artisan optimize

Comment: Do all other routes work fine?

Comment: They are seemingly all working, except for this one (added when updating the composer package).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239389/discussion-between-siddharth-bhansali-and-erik-t).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given all the other routes work, and the route got added later, it is a cache issue. You could try `php artisan route:clear` OR `php artisan optimize:clear` (I prefer the latter since it clears all cache, and not just route). It should start working then.

Note:

1. `*:clear` commands do NOT build the cache again.
2. The `optimize` command doesn't work with Route closures, so if you have that, you'd have to comment it out and then run the `optimize` command.

Comment: Php artisan optimize:clear solved the route not found issue, but there seems to be other major issues related to the Laravel Application not finding files inside my composer package on the server. But since optimize:clear solved my initital problem I am going to accept this as an answer.

Comment: That sounds like a very weird problem, but if you can't solve, do post another question, I'm sure someone would help you out.

Answer (score -1):

First, clear all cahe & route cache : `php artisan optimize` Then if it's not working then sea your all Route `php artisan route:list`

Comment: As stated in the question, php artisan route:list does show the route. Php artisan optimize did solve a part of the problem but not the problem as a whole.